# How can I specify the table I want to extract from a URL into R when there are multiple tables on the webpage?

Tags: html, r, database, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract MLB player stats from Baseball Reference. I've navigated to the URL that houses this data and execute the following code in my RStudio.

```
install.packages('rvest')
library(rvest)
url <- 'http://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2017-standard-batting.shtml#player_standard_batting::none'
webpage <- read_html(url)
b_table <- html_nodes(webpage, 'table')
b <- html_table(b_table)[[1]]
head(b)
```

This snipet of code however extracts the first table on the webpage, not the one that I need. I've tried using various pieces of the html code to specify the correct table but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Just change the `[[1]]` to whichever table you need

Comment: I was just prompted with the following error message: Error in html_table(b_table)[[2]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476819/not-able-to-scrape-a-second-table-within-a-page-using-rvest) very similar question.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!