# Not able to scrape all tables within a page behind comments using rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to scrape all tables from this page: https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ARI/ARI202311010.shtml

I have since found that some tables are within comment tags, so using the code adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476819/not-able-to-scrape-a-second-table-within-a-page-using-rvest), I have:

```
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(stringi)

urlbbref <- read_html("https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ARI/ARI202311010.shtml")
# First table is in the markup
table_one <- xml_find_all(urlbbref, "//table") %>% html_table

# Additional tables are within the comment tags, ie <!-- tables -->
# Which is why your xpath is missing them.
# First get the commented nodes
alt_tables <- xml2::xml_find_all(urlbbref,"//comment()") %>% {
  #Find only commented nodes that contain the regex for html table markup
  raw_parts <- as.character(.[grep("\\</?table", as.character(.))])
  # Remove the comment begin and end tags
  strip_html <- stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(raw_parts, c("<\\!--","-->"),c("",""),
                                                vectorize_all = FALSE)
  # Loop through the pieces that have tables within markup and 
  # apply the same functions
  lapply(grep("<table", strip_html, value = TRUE), function(i){
    rvest::html_table(xml_find_all(read_html(i), "//table")) %>% 
      .[[1]]
  })
}
# Put all the data frames into a list.
all_tables <- c(
  table_one, alt_tables
)
```

However, the second pitching table does not appear (for Arizona). I can get the first using

```
all_tables[9]
```

Output:

```
> all_tables[9]
[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 × 27
  Pitching         IP     H     R    ER    BB    SO    HR   ERA    BF   Pit   Str  Ctct   StS
  <chr>         <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Nathan Eoval…   6       4     0     0     5     5     0  2.95    27    97    60    40     7
2 Aroldis Chap…   0.2     0     0     0     1     1     0  2.25     3    10     4     2     1
3 Josh Sborz, …   2.1     1     0     0     0     4     0  0.75     8    31    20    11     1
4 Team Totals     9       5     0     0     6    10     0  0       38   138    84    53     9
# ℹ 13 more variables: StL <int>, GB <int>, FB <int>, LD <int>, Unk <int>, GSc <int>,
#   IR <int>, IS <int>, WPA <dbl>, aLI <dbl>, cWPA <chr>, acLI <dbl>, RE24 <dbl>
```

But for some reason the second table doesn't appear and I can't figure out why or how to obtain it?

Comment: ok thanks I don't have ublock origin. All tables appeared in the output except the second pitching table which is why I am stumped. Could this table be the only one loaded with javascript?

Comment: I misspoke, w.r.t. Javascript. I should have said, block *all* javascript, as rvest doesn't run a browser, it just pulls the (html) file at the url

Comment: it is the pitching table for Arizona Diamondbacks. The first one for Texas is the one I have shown above (all_tables[9]). But for some reason this table does not appear.

Comment: so where specifically would I look to block javascript? Should this be done in R?

Comment: you can do it through your browser. You don't need to do it now, it's just good practice, for when loading web pages, if you're unsure if something is in the html file itself, or is piped in from somewhere else

Comment: that and looking at the network requests for json files

Comment: I see. But how is it that the pitching table does not output when the above code is run? The pitching table for Texas is there but not the table for Arizona?

Comment: I blocked javascript, but unfortunately I still could not get the table to appear. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: need to go and have dinner, but the following code might give you a lead: `read_html(path) |> html_nodes(xpath = '//comment()[contains(., "div class")]')`, where path is the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
pacman::p_load(rvest, tidyverse)

path <- "https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ARI/ARI202311010.shtml"

path |>
  read_html() |>
  html_nodes(xpath = '//comment()[contains(., "div class")]') |> 
  map(\(x) x |> 
             as.character() |> 
             str_remove_all("<!--|-->") |> 
             read_html() |> 
             html_table()) |> 
  unlist(recursive = FALSE)
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 14 × 24
   Batting    AB     R     H   RBI    BB    SO    PA     BA    OBP    SLG    OPS
   <chr>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 "Marcu…     5     1     2     2     0     1     5  0.224  0.28   0.355  0.636
 2 "Corey…     4     1     2     0     1     0     5  0.318  0.451  0.682  1.13 
 3 "Evan …     5     0     1     0     0     4     5  0.3    0.417  0.5    0.917
 4 "Mitch…     4     0     1     1     0     1     4  0.226  0.317  0.434  0.751
 5 "Josh …     4     1     1     0     0     1     4  0.308  0.329  0.538  0.867
 6 "Natha…     3     1     1     0     1     0     4  0.212  0.278  0.379  0.657
 7 "Jonah…     4     1     1     1     0     1     4  0.212  0.268  0.348  0.616
 8 "Leody…     4     0     0     0     0     1     4  0.175  0.299  0.281  0.579
 9 "Travi…     3     0     0     0     1     0     4  0.333  0.4    0.444  0.844
10 ""         NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA     NA     NA     NA    
11 "Natha…    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA     NA     NA     NA    
12 "Arold…    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA     NA     NA     NA    
13 "Josh …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA     NA     NA     NA    
14 "Team …    36     5     9     4     3     9    39  0.25   0.308  0.361  0.669
# ℹ 12 more variables: Pit <int>, Str <int>, WPA <dbl>, aLI <dbl>,
#   `WPA+` <dbl>, `WPA-` <dbl>, cWPA <chr>, acLI <dbl>, RE24 <dbl>, PO <int>,
#   A <int>, Details <chr>

[[2]]
# A tibble: 16 × 24
   Batting    AB     R     H   RBI    BB    SO    PA     BA    OBP    SLG    OPS
   <chr>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 "Corbi…     4     0     1     0     1     0     5  0.273  0.364  0.409  0.773
 2 "Ketel…     2     0     0     0     3     1     5  0.329  0.38   0.534  0.914
 3 "Gabri…     3     0     0     0     0     2     4  0.238  0.304  0.444  0.749
 4 "Chris…     3     0     1     0     1     1     4  0.217  0.36   0.35   0.71 
 5 "Tommy…     3     0     0     0     1     1     4  0.279  0.297  0.475  0.772
 6 "Lourd…     4     0     1     0     0     0     4  0.273  0.29   0.455  0.744
 7 "Alek …     4     0     1     0     0     0     4  0.222  0.271  0.463  0.734
 8 "Evan …     3     0     1     0     0     1     3  0.167  0.226  0.229  0.456
 9 "Pavin…     1     0     0     0     0     1     1  0.3    0.364  0.3    0.664
10 "Emman…     0     0     0     0     0     0     0  0.235  0.278  0.294  0.572
11 "Geral…     4     0     0     0     0     3     4  0.275  0.362  0.392  0.754
12 ""         NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA     NA     NA     NA    
13 "Zac G…    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA     NA     NA     NA    
14 "Kevin…    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA     NA     NA     NA    
15 "Paul …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA     NA     NA     NA    
16 "Team …    31     0     5     0     6    10    38  0.161  0.297  0.194  0.491
# ℹ 12 more variables: Pit <int>, Str <int>, WPA <dbl>, aLI <dbl>,
#   `WPA+` <dbl>, `WPA-` <dbl>, cWPA <chr>, acLI <dbl>, RE24 <dbl>, PO <int>,
#   A <int>, Details <chr>

[[3]]
# A tibble: 4 × 27
  Pitching        IP     H     R    ER    BB    SO    HR   ERA    BF   Pit   Str
  <chr>        <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1 Nathan Eova…   6       4     0     0     5     5     0  2.95    27    97    60
2 Aroldis Cha…   0.2     0     0     0     1     1     0  2.25     3    10     4
3 Josh Sborz,…   2.1     1     0     0     0     4     0  0.75     8    31    20
4 Team Totals    9       5     0     0     6    10     0  0       38   138    84
# ℹ 15 more variables: Ctct <int>, StS <int>, StL <int>, GB <int>, FB <int>,
#   LD <int>, Unk <int>, GSc <int>, IR <int>, IS <int>, WPA <dbl>, aLI <dbl>,
#   cWPA <chr>, acLI <dbl>, RE24 <dbl>

[[4]]
# A tibble: 4 × 27
  Pitching        IP     H     R    ER    BB    SO    HR   ERA    BF   Pit   Str
  <chr>        <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1 Zac Gallen,…   6.1     3     1     1     1     6     0  4.54    23    83    57
2 Kevin Ginkel   1.2     1     0     0     2     1     0  0        8    32    15
3 Paul Sewald    1       5     4     4     0     2     1  5.4      8    20    14
4 Team Totals    9       9     5     5     3     9     1  5       39   135    86
# ℹ 15 more variables: Ctct <int>, StS <int>, StL <int>, GB <int>, FB <int>,
#   LD <int>, Unk <int>, GSc <int>, IR <int>, IS <int>, WPA <dbl>, aLI <dbl>,
#   cWPA <chr>, acLI <dbl>, RE24 <dbl>

[[5]]
# A tibble: 10 × 3
      X1 X2               X3   
   <int> <chr>            <chr>
 1     1 Marcus Semien    2B   
 2     2 Corey Seager     SS   
 3     3 Evan Carter      LF   
 4     4 Mitch Garver     DH   
 5     5 Josh Jung        3B   
 6     6 Nathaniel Lowe   1B   
 7     7 Jonah Heim       C    
 8     8 Leody Taveras    CF   
 9     9 Travis Jankowski RF   
10    NA Nathan Eovaldi   P    

[[6]]
# A tibble: 10 × 3
      X1 X2                  X3   
   <int> <chr>               <chr>
 1     1 Corbin Carroll      RF   
 2     2 Ketel Marte         2B   
 3     3 Gabriel Moreno      C    
 4     4 Christian Walker    1B   
 5     5 Tommy Pham          DH   
 6     6 Lourdes Gurriel Jr. LF   
 7     7 Alek Thomas         CF   
 8     8 Evan Longoria       3B   
 9     9 Geraldo Perdomo     SS   
10    NA Zac Gallen          P    

[[7]]
# A tibble: 5 × 12
  Inn   Score   Out RoB   `Pit(cnt)`     `R/O` `@Bat` Batter Pitcher wWPA  wWE  
  <chr> <chr> <int> <chr> <chr>          <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <chr>
1 t7    0-0       0 1--   2,(1-0) BX     ""    TEX    Evan … Zac Ga… 17%   73%  
2 t7    0-0       0 -23   2,(0-1) FX     "R"   TEX    Mitch… Zac Ga… 10%   82%  
3 b5    0-0       2 123   1,(0-0) X      "O"   ARI    Lourd… Nathan… 9%    50%  
4 t9    1-0       0 12-   1,(0-0) X      "RR"  TEX    Jonah… Paul S… 9%    98%  
5 b3    0-0       1 -23   6,(2-2) B*BFF… "O"   ARI    Chris… Nathan… 8%    43%  
# ℹ 1 more variable: `Play Description` <chr>

[[8]]
# A tibble: 120 × 12
   Inn      Score Out   RoB   `Pit(cnt)` `R/O` `@Bat` Batter Pitcher wWPA  wWE  
   <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <chr>
 1 "Top of… "Top… "Top… "Top… "Top of t… "Top… "Top … "Top … "Top o… Top … Top …
 2 "t1"     "0-0" "0"   "---" "4,(2-1) … "O"   "TEX"  "Marc… "Zac G… -2%   48%  
 3 "t1"     "0-0" "1"   "---" "5,(1-2) … "O"   "TEX"  "Core… "Zac G… -2%   46%  
 4 "t1"     "0-0" "2"   "---" "4,(1-2) … "O"   "TEX"  "Evan… "Zac G… -1%   45%  
 5 ""       ""    ""    ""    ""         ""    ""     ""     ""      0 ru… 0 ru…
 6 "Bottom… "Bot… "Bot… "Bot… "Bottom o… "Bot… "Bott… "Bott… "Botto… Bott… Bott…
 7 "b1"     "0-0" "0"   "---" "4,(3-0) … ""    "ARI"  "Corb… "Natha… -3%   42%  
 8 "b1"     "0-0" "0"   "1--" "1,(0-0) … ""    "ARI"  "Kete… "Natha… -2%   39%  
 9 "b1"     "0-0" "0"   "-2-" "3,(0-2) … "O"   "ARI"  "Kete… "Natha… 1%    41%  
10 "b1"     "0-0" "1"   "--3" "3,(1-1) … "O"   "ARI"  "Gabr… "Natha… 6%    46%  
# ℹ 110 more rows
# ℹ 1 more variable: `Play Description` <chr>
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: thank you! That is much simpler than what I had. Perhaps I was over-thinking it? The last step is to rbind both the batting tables [1] and [2] and the pitching tables [3] and [4]. How can I do this with the code above? I also need to remove all the `NA` values from each.

Comment: can you also explain what `pacman::p_load(rvest, tidyverse)` does? Am I able to load the libraries separately and still get the desired outcome?

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pacman/versions/0.5.1/topics/p_load

Comment: For the first comment, you have some experience with R right? I don't need to tell you how to save a thing or access the elements of a list or filter out rows with NA values ? Your code is quite advanced, so I assume you would be capable of doing these simpler things (or at least figuring them out on your own)

Comment: @Mark I have an Apointment in a few weeks and found anouther error so Im Quite stressed about it, can you have a Look (and save me again :D) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77648968/missing-definition